# Payment queuing system for PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, queue, payment

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle payment processing to prevent duplicate payment submissions. I'm using PHP (specifically CakePHP 2.3.8) with Balanced Payments to handle the payment processing.

I've noticed on my server logs that I've had multiple requests submitted all within a second for something usually related to wordpress or phpmyadmin, such as

```
ip.address.here - [08/Jul/2014:15:03:12 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 320 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
ip.address.here - [08/Jul/2014:15:03:12 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 320 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
ip.address.here - [08/Jul/2014:15:03:12 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 320 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
ip.address.here - [08/Jul/2014:15:03:13 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 320 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
```

I'm worried about someone trying something similar (accidental or not) but with a payment. What is the most effective way to handle a situation like above where multiple requests come in very quickly, regardless if it's a "hacker" or just a hiccup in the system? If I use a queuing system like [this one, speficially for CakePHP](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Queue-Plugin) how would I keep track of previously processed entries in order to detect duplicate submissions?

Say I have a queue of 3 entries. While processing entry 1 would I check entry 2 and 3 to make sure they're not duplicate information? If they are, then just delete them?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you should just save a Session identifier that stays the same until the transaction has finished or has been canceled. Usually the payment gateway takes that session identifier to check that you're not duplicating the transaction.

Also, the Payment Gateway should detect duplicates (i.e. same card info, same amount in a short period of time) and will return an error back to you, letting you know what happened.

So, you just remember to keep track of your unique id and reset it when the transaction is completed. If your're keeping a shopping bag, and that expires, make the transaction id expire at that same time. And finally, make sure to disable the submit button with javascript so the users don't tap it more than once.